# iOS Storing a pointer

Tags: ios, ios5

In my ios application i want to store an object's reference. This object can be an instance from interface A,B,C or D. I know that it's always going to be one from these four, but never know which one. How can i represent this object in my code?

Sincerely, Zoli

Comment: what is the question, please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represent it as type id.

```
id ptr;
```

Also, be aware of the possibility that you can specialise type **id** to some protocol.

```
id <SomeProtocol>;
```

Answer (score 0):

what i understand that you should make a shared instance of that object.
example:-

1. make a new class named SavedReference.
2. and write in implementation file this code

Code:

```
static SavedReference *sharedInstance = nil;  //if using iOS5 or above no need to nil it.    
+(SavedReference*)sharedInstance    
{     
    @synchronized(self)
    {   
         if(!sharedInstance)     
         {   
              sharedInstance = [[self alloc]init];
              return sharedInstance;
         }
     }
    return nil; 
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];    
    if(self)    
    {
        //initialize variables
    }

    return self;
 }
```

And Call this class as `[[SavedReference sharedInstance]  write ur method]`